# How do I get the member's roles, instead of a list with the role name and id for info command?

Tags: discord.py

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def info(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
        if member is None:
            member = ctx.author
            name = str(member.name)
            avatar = str(member.avatar_url)
            bot = str(member.bot)
            created = str(member.created_at)
            joined = str(member.joined_at)
            id = str(member.id)
            roles = member.roles
            emb = discord.Embed(
                title="Member Information",
                color=discord.Color.blue()
            )
            emb.set_thumbnail(url=avatar)
            emb.add_field(name="Member", value=name, inline=True)
            emb.add_field(name="User ID", value=id, inline=True)
            emb.add_field(name="Created On", value=created, inline=False)
            emb.add_field(name="Joined At", value=joined, inline=True)
            emb.add_field(name="Bot", value=bot, inline=False)
            emb.add_field(name="Roles", value=roles, inline=True)
            await ctx.send(embed=emb)
        else:
            name = str(member.name)
            avatar = str(member.avatar_url)
            bot = str(member.bot)
            created = str(member.created_at)
            joined = str(member.joined_at)
            id = str(member.id)
            roles = member.roles
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title="Member Information",
                color=discord.Color.blue()
            )
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=avatar)
            embed.add_field(name="Member", value=name, inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="User ID", value=id, inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="Created On", value=created, inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Joined At", value=joined, inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="Bot", value=bot, inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Roles", value=roles, inline=True)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

This is my command and I can't figure out a way to have the bot mention the role for the command instead of all this:
`[<Role id=794621342585847829 name='@everyone'>, <Role id=794728482365898752 name='Members'>, <Role id=801106344777351179 name='Alpha Testers'>, <Role id=794624055969054741 name='Server Dev'>, <Role id=809075308808372234 name='Dev Team'>, <Role id=794623964436627466 name='Bot Dev'>]`
I think thats what the bot sends when you have `member.roles` but idk how to change that, I've try `members.roles.mention`, but it just sends an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`member.roles` will always give out a list of roles where also the `@everyone`-role is included, all sorted by their position in the role hierarchy.  You can have a look at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member%20roles#discord.Member.roles).

**Try this instead:**

```py
roles1 = [role.mention for role in user.roles if role != ctx.guild.default_role]
emb.add_field(name=f"Roles ({len(roles1)}):", value=', '.join(roles1), inline=False)
```

This will mention the roles and separate them with a `,`. It also excludes the `@everyone`-role.

If you want to remove the counter just remove `{len(roles1)}`.

***This is a possible output:***

[image]